# java.io.FileNotFoundException (Trying to deserialize)

Tags: java, android, file, io

I'm trying to deserialize an XML file into an Object.
My code fails on the line:

```
new FileInputStream(mySearch)
```

with a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

So, I added the:  if (exists) block to see if the file could be found another way.

I've googled the error and read other threads of discussion. Based on those discussions, I've tried **FIVE** different ways of specifying the file path and name. (See the commented out attempts)

The desired behavior is that I figure out what is wrong with my syntax for the path and file name, so that the file will be found and deserialized.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.beans.XMLDecoder;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // 5/20/2018 T. Pfaff - Added XMLDecoder Deserialization of XML file into EquationLib/LibSets/EquationSet

    //===========================================================================================
    //Below are the FIVE different ways that I've tried to get it to find the file

    String myFileStr = "C:\\Users\\Terence\\Documents\\Meditate-Lemniscate\\Test_Single.xml";
    //String myFileStr = "c:\\users\\terence\\documents\\meditate-lemniscate\\test_single.xml";
    //String myFileStr = "C:/Users/Terence/Documents/Meditate-Lemniscate/Test_Single.xml";
    //String myFileStr = "c:/users/terence/documents/meditate-lemniscate/test_single.xml";
    //String myFileStr = "Test_Single.xml";

    //===========================================================================================

    String myEqSetName = "";
    Integer myCnt = 0;
    EquationLib equationLib = new EquationLib();
    TextView myTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    //=============================================================================
    //This block of code ALWAYS results in "Does NOT Exist"
    //no matter which value I use for myFileStr

    File mySearch = new File(myFileStr);
    boolean exists = mySearch.exists();

    if (exists) {
        myTV.setText("YES EXISTS: " + myFileStr);
    } else {
        myTV.setText("Does NOT Exist: " + myFileStr);
    }
    //==============================================================================


    XMLDecoder decoder=null;

    // The first statement in the try block throws the exception:
    //java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Terence\Documents\Meditate-Lemniscate\Test_Single.xml (No such file or directory)

    try{
        FileInputStream myFileIS = new FileInputStream(mySearch);
        decoder = new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(myFileIS));
        equationLib = (EquationLib) decoder.readObject();

        myCnt = equationLib.libSets.size();
        myEqSetName = equationLib.libSets.get(0).equationSet.name;

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //myTV.setText(myCnt.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: Open a `cmd` window, change to that directory, type `dir`; then copy/paste the output into your question (use code formatting)

Comment: Instead of trying different ways to specify the file name, did you actually verify that the file exists? E.g. run `dir C:\Users\Terence\Documents\Meditate-Lemniscate\Test_Single.xml` on a command-line.

Comment: Those paths look like Windows paths, but your code uses Android libraries, where is it running?

Comment: @Andreas - The dir command shows the file exists and displays its size.

Answer (score 2):

The Android emulator doesn't have access to the host's file system. You can bundle the XML file into your `project_root\res\raw\` folder and then open it as a resource:

```
// Open project_root\res\raw\my_file.xml

InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_file);
```

Or copy it onto the virtual device's storage and then open the local path:

```
adb push C:\Temp\my_file.xml /sdcard/my_file.xml
```

Comment: I created an "xml" folder under "res" and put the file in there. Now I get the red squiggly line under (R.xml.Test_Single) and the message reads: "expected resource of type Raw".

Comment: If you plan to read it as a raw resource with your own decoder, try putting into the `raw` subdirectory instead of `xml`.

Comment: Now, for some reason, wherever I use "(R....)" it is highlighted red and says "Cannot resolve symbol R".

Comment: Based on your suggestion @jspcal, I am now trying: 'InputStream stream = getResources().getString(R.xml.Test_1_gend);' But, it is highlighted red and says: Cannot resolve symbol xml I put the xml file into a folder under \res\xml Is there something else I need to do to register the xml file?